# Jenkins setup to user selenium java scripts

Tags: java, jenkins

i am new to code and selenium, is there any way to build a job on Jenkins to run scripts automatically at a specific time everyday? need steps to follow

Comment: This is not a Selenium problem! This is a problem with you not knowing how to Google "Jenkins documentation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  In the Jenkins Build configuration, you can use the `Build Periodically` build step, then you are able to specify a `cron` date.

If you want it to run at 05:00 every day, then you'd specify

```
0 5 * * *
```

Which in cron, means "05:00 every day"